# Save Excel file to local webserver (where site is running)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have the following code that is used to save an Excel file when the user execute a function:

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = orders;
gv.DataBind();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MMDDYYYY.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.Charset = string.Empty;
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gv.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

This works fine and the filename follows the prescribed format. How can I edit this code so that it also saves the Excel file to the webserver so that if someone wants to run the query for the same date in the future, all I do is pass them the existing file, rather than rerunning the query?

Comment: `Response.WriteFile(path);`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = orders;
gv.DataBind();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MMDDYYYY.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.Charset = string.Empty;
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gv.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());

    // Save your content file to the disk
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\YourServerPath\MMDDYYYY.xls", sw.ToString());

Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```